# Moment.js adding difference between multiple dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using the following code to get difference between two dates in hrs, minutes and seconds, which I will save later in database as a string field. So I was wondering if it is possible to use Moment.js library or any Javascript functionally in order to get the total number of hours, minutes and seconds for all date differences saved in the database (ex. 02:24:33 + 03:12:20 + 12:33:33) as one final HH:MM:SS taking in consideration that the HH could exceed 24 if the total number of hours summed exceeded 24? Thanks

```
$('.set-start-time').on("dp.change",function (e) {
   $('.set-end-time').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
$('.set-end-time').on("dp.change",function (e) {
   $('.set-start-time').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);

    var now  = $('.set-start-time').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString();
    var then = $('.set-end-time').data('DateTimePicker').getDate().toLocaleString();

    console.log(moment.utc(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss"));
    //Output here come in format ex. 02:42:33

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too late for this to matter, but maybe something like this would help:

http://jsfiddle.net/8s8v3evf/8/

**tl;dr**
once you have your diff:

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
    var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
   return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

function diffAsString(diff_ms) {
    var hours = Math.floor(diff_ms / 3600000);
    diff_ms -= (hours * 3600000);

    var minutes = Math.floor(diff_ms / 60000);
    diff_ms -= (minutes * 60000);

    var seconds = Math.floor(diff_ms / 1000);

    return zeroPad(hours, 2) + ':' + zeroPad(minutes, 2) + ':' + zeroPad(seconds, 2);
}
```